# COUNT CASE and WHEN statement in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

How to use COUNT CASE and WHEN statement in MySQL query, to count when data is NULL and when it is not NULL in one MySQL query?

Comment: `COUNT(col)` = Number of `NOT NULL`. `COUNT(*) - COUNT(col)` = Number of `NULL` Why do you need `CASE`?

Comment: Can i use case in COUNT function..?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
             WHEN t.your_column IS NULL THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS numNull,
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN t.your_column IS NOT NULL THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS numNotNull
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

That will sum up the column NULL & not NULL for the entire table.  It's likely you need a GROUP BY clause, depending on needs.

Comment: And now how to echo this values, how much is NULL and how much is not NULL.

Comment: @Ivan Tanasijevic: There're examples in the [mysql_query documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: If you want to achieve that with `COUNT` you can use null (not counted) and another arbitrary value (counted).

Comment: Please note that SUM will return NULL if there are no rows selected (i.e. the table is empty or a where condition excludes all rows). You can still obtain a "0" by coding the select this way: IFNULL(SUM(...), 0)

Answer (score 3):

You can exploit the fact that COUNT only counts non-null values:

```
SELECT COUNT(IFNULL(t.your_column, 1)) AS numNull,
       COUNT(t.your_column) AS numNotNull
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Another approach is to use the fact that logical conditions get evaluated to numeric 0 and 1, so this will also work:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(t.your_column IS NULL), 0) AS numNull,
       IFNULL(SUM(t.your_column IS NOT NULL), 0) AS numNotNull
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Please note that SUM will return NULL if there are no rows selected (i.e. the table is empty or a where condition excludes all rows), this is the reason for the IFNULL statements.