# Count multiple CASE occurrences in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for solution for the following issue:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN p.value LIKE '%foo%' THEN 'foos'
    WHEN p.value LIKE '%bar%' THEN 'bars'
    WHEN p.value LIKE '%bakar%' THEN 'bakars'
    ELSE p.value END as value,
COUNT(*) as count FROM table_a p GROUP BY value
```

Values are something like:

```
foo, bar, foo and bar, bakar, bakarbar, foobar
```

Result of this query is:

```
 value    count
 foos       3
 bars       2
 bakars     1
```

This code successfully counts occurrences, but the CASE stops at first match.
Is there a way to do this?

```
value    count
 foos       3
 bars       4
 bakars     2
```

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045124/count-case-and-when-statement-in-mysql

Comment: you group by a other value. please show us all values of p.value

Comment: @BerndBuffen, same column. Qualified and not...

Comment: no -  sample : p.value = 'bar' is not the same like 'bars' in the group but in the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a single `case` expression no, you cannot achieve what you want precisely because `case` stops at the first match.

You need to have separate `case` expressions or `if()` function calls to achieve the expected outcome. If you do not mind having the results in different columns, then use conditional counting:

```
select count(if(p.value LIKE '%foo%',1,null)) as foos,
       ...
from table_a p
```

If you insist on receiving the counts in the same column, then use `union`:

```
select 'foos' as `value`, count(*) from table_a where table_a.value LIKE '%foo%'
union
...
```

Comment: I was afraid this is the case. There's way too much data for union in my case, so I'll have to look for alternative solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the dynamic part of the accepted answer in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UNION` if you want to count more than 1 occurrence in each string:

```
SELECT 'foos' as value, count(*)
FROM YourTable
WHERE p.value LIKE '%foo%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bars' as value, count(*)
FROM YourTable
WHERE p.value LIKE '%bar%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bakars' as value, count(*)
FROM YourTable
WHERE p.value LIKE '%bakar%'
```

Comment: While not fitting solution for my case, it's a valid answer as well, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
select      w.word 
           ,count(*)

from        table_a 

            join  (         select 'foo'  as word 
                  union all select 'bar' 
                  union all select 'bakar'
                  ) w

            on   value like concat('%',w.word,'%')

group by    w.word  
;
```

Comment: concat appears to have some collation issues for me, I'll investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add your table DDL? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 SELECT 
    (select count(p1.value) from table_a p1 where p1.value LIKE '%foo%') as foos,
    (select count(p2.value) from table_a p2 where p2.value LIKE '%bar%') as bars,
    (select count(p3.value) from table_a p3 where p3.value LIKE '%bakar%') as bakars
     FROM table_a p GROUP BY p.value
```

Comment: Interesting solution to put it in rows. I'll look into that.