# MYSQL: Display the total number of dependents for each employee for employees who have at most 1 dependents

Tags: mysql

So I have to execute this query in **MYSQL**

```
Display the total number of dependents for each employee for employees who have at most 1 dependents
```

which is easy enough but the problem I'm facing is that some of the values in the **DEPENDENT_ID** column of the **DEPENDENT** table are **zero** which **MYSQL** is also including in the **COUNT(DEPENDENT_ID)** function. I can't even change it to **NULL** to make my code work (by using IFNULL) since the **DEPENDENT_ID** is a **PRIMARY KEY** along with **EMPID**. `PRIMARY KEY (EMPID, DEPENDENT_ID)`. Here is the data for your reference:

**DEPENDENT** table:

| EMPID | DEPENDENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 302 |
| 102 | 301 |
| 103 | 302 |
| 104 | 0 |
| 105 | 0 |

**DESCRIBE DEPENDENT** table:

| FIELD | TYPE | NULL | KEY | DEFAULT | EXTRA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EMPID | INT | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| DEPENDENT_ID | INT | NO | PRI | NULL |  |

So far, I've done this which is not the desired result.

```
SELECT EMPID, COUNT(DEPENDENT_ID)
FROM DEPENDENT
GROUP BY EMPID
HAVING COUNT(DEPENDENT_ID)<=1;
```

| EMPID | COUNT(DEPENDENT_ID) |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 |
| 102 | 1 |
| 103 | 1 |
| 104 | 1 |
| 105 | 1 |

I really don't know how to make the **ones** against **EMPID** `104` and `105` change to **zeros** because these employees technically have no dependents. In the **DEPENDENT** table the **DEPENDENT_ID** of `104` and `105` show up as **ZERO** because I had to insert some value as the column is **NOT NULL**. So I put zero instead of any specific ID (like 302, 303, etc).

I'm expecting the result to be like this:

| EMPID | COUNT(DEPENDENT_ID) |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 |
| 102 | 1 |
| 103 | 1 |
| 104 | 0 |
| 105 | 0 |

I've tried a lot of techniques but they all result in some kind of syntax error and Google couldn't help as well. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The number will be 1, as you are limiting it to employees who only have 1 dependent...

Comment: Please post sample data and query as text. AND make the sample representative as is no employee has more than 1 dependent. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Note that it would be completely sensible (read: correct) to just not add rows that do not describe dependencies in a table that describe dependencies - then counting rows in that table would not count rows that do not have dependents.

Comment: Nevertheless, what you are probably looking for is something like `count(case when dependent_id > 0 then 1 end)`, see e.g. [COUNT CASE and WHEN statement in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5045124), or something like `select count(*) from .... where dependent_id > 0 having ...`.

Comment: @Solar Mike Yeah but I am looking for the solution to display 0 dependents where the dependent_id = 0. Atmost 1 dependents so less than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
SELECT EMPID, COUNT(NULLIF(DEPENDENT_ID, 0)) AS real_count
FROM DEPENDENT
GROUP BY EMPID
HAVING real_count<=1;
```

`COUNT()` ignores NULLs. I know you are storing 0 which signifies "no dependent" and can't change this in the table.

You can make an expression with the [`NULLIF()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_nullif) that substitutes NULL for 0 as it counts them.

Comment: Thank you @Bill Karwin. This easily solved the problem.

Comment: @Bill Karwin, sir, I added two topics about an errata and an alternative solution regarding your book at forum.devtalk.com. Please check it out at your convenience.

Comment: @blabla_bingo Please do not use Stack Overflow for personal communication. I am notified when topics are added on DevTalk pertaining to my book.